# Using PDO without binding

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sanitization

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id');

$stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => $_GET['user_id']));

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I'm using PDO like that, do I need to sanitise GET parameter?

I know if I do `$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $_GET['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);` than it is not a problem. But is my way safe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. The only differences between `execute` and `bind*` are:

- `execute` accepts several parameters at once, while you have to `bind*` each one individually
- `bind*` allows you to specify the parameter type, while `execute` binds everything as strings

Passing parameters to `execute` is mostly a convenience shorthand, it's still safe.