# PHP MYSQL Prepared Statements - Difference

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to make my SQL calls more secure and I encounter 2 ways of making prepared statements, I was wondering if there is any difference between them.

This is the Query:

```
$query = 
            "INSERT INTO companies
            VALUES(
                NULL, 
                :name,
                :assignation,
                :priority
                )";
```

1)

```
        $statement = $pdoDbInstance->prepare($query);

        $statement->bindValue(':name', $name);
        $statement->bindValue(':assignation', $assignation);
        $statement->bindValue(':priority', $priority);

        $result = $statement->execute();
```

2)

```
$statement = $pdoDbInstance->prepare($query);

$result = $statement->execute(array(":name" => $name, ":assignation" => $assignation, ":priority" => $priority));
```

Is there any significant difference between them????

Comment: Not that im aware of, But the first method is nice when using a loop

Comment: yes, this other post answers my question [PDO without Binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110329/using-pdo-without-binding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12392590/2124401, it is a matter of whether you need to enforce the datatype. Execute always passes strings, so if you want something different or a specific datatype, use bindValue or bindParam. Otherwise, they are just a matter of preference.